# Pull any machine specific information from Windows audit log?

Tags: c#, windows, event-log, filesystemwatcher

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406720/programmatically-determine-user-who-last-modified-file-on-windows/8406836).

I followed the accepted answer and thought I was satisfied with the results but ran into a roadblock.

**The Setup**

I'm running my C# program from the server that monitors a directory. Any time a file is modified, FileSystemWatcher triggers an event that causes the program to check the security audit logs (which have been turned on, see previous question's solution).

**The Problem**

My problem is that when I check the security logs after a remote user has modified a file, they are logged as an anonymous user. Specifically "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM". Is there any way to pull unique information from these security logs that will help me differentiate the users modifying the files?

**The Deets**

I'm using `EventLog` to read the security logs like this:

```
EventLog log = new EventLog("security");
EventLogEntryCollection col = log.Entries;
//...
string username = entry.UserName;
```

Comment: Let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the audit entries to see what information is included in them?

Comment: I have. the only relevant information I can distinguish is a 'Client Logon ID' but the field appears to never be populated.

Comment: Then your answer is probably no.

Answer (score 1):

This may help
    string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

Comment: Sorry friend, you are 5 years too late.

Comment: hope this helps some one else :)