# How to know last modified user of any file in c#?

Tags: c#, last-modified

I am trying to get last modified by user name but I am not able to get the user name. I searched lot on [Google](https://www.google.co.in) but I am confuse now. Because In some thread I found that last modified user is not able to get. And Other link gives some code. I used that code but last modified user is not getting retrieved.

Is there any one who get the last modified user name using c# code?
Is it possible?

Comment: string user = System.IO.File.GetAccessControl("filepath").GetOwner(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString(); this code retrieve file owner

Comment: @Grant Winney I have tried the code of the link which is provided by HABJAN.

Answer (score 3):

This should give you the last modified file and the user who changed it:

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
var lastModified = dir.GetFiles()
    .OrderByDescending(fi => fi.LastWriteTime)
    .First();
string modifiedBy = lastModified.GetAccessControl()
    .GetOwner(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString();
```

"Powered by": [Finding the user who modified the shared drive folder files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19888612/finding-the-user-who-modified-the-shared-drive-folder-files)

**Edit**: actually this gives you only the owner of the file that was last modified.

It seems that windows simply doesn't keep track of this. You could use a [`FilesystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do it yourself.

Comment: this function return user who create this file

Comment: @RajuJoshi: which function? `LastWriteTime` is the time a file was last written to.

Comment: string modifiedBy = lastModified.GetAccessControl()
    .GetOwner(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString();           this line return file owner, not a modifier

Comment: @RajuJoshi: you're right. I'm afraid that windows doesn't store this so you need to keep track of it yourself. One way, use a `FileSystemWatcher` (edited my answer acc.).

Comment: string modifiedBy = lastModified.GetAccessControl()
    .GetOwner(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString();     its also not working if user is from another domain