# C# FileSystemWatcher watch changes on network drive which is only done by current system

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I am following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st80atsf(v=vs.110).aspx) example of `FileSystemWatcher`, On the top of this, I have created windows form application which will open whenever any `.txt` file is created and renamed in Z drive.

I have built the console application and deployed to two system and both systems are listening to same network drive (I have mapped a network drive as Z drive in both systems)

However, the problem is whenever I am creating or renaming `.txt` file in network drive both system's forms are opening which is logical since both deployed console applications are listening to the same location.

> But my requirement is " The form should be opened in that system only
>   who is performing the action of creating or renaming that `.txt` file."
>
> Is there any way I can achieve this Or is this even possible with `fileSystemWatcher` class?

Here is the code snippet.

```
public class Watcher
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        Run();

    }

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public static void Run()
    {
        string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();


        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher("Z:\\", "*.txt");
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
           | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        // Add event handlers.
        //watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged); //Fires everytime files is changed (mulitple times in copy operation)
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

        // Begin watching.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        // Wait for the user to quit the program.
        Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
        while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
    }

    // Define the event handlers.
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
        Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.Run(new Feedback.Form1(e.FullPath));//Here I am opening new form for feedback
    }

    private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
        Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.Run(new Feedback.Form1(e.FullPath));//Here I am opening new form for feedback
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FileSystemWatcher` *may* notify you that *something* happened, and you *might* also be able to deduce *what* happened, but don't count on it. It's a quite limited and unreliable component in my (and [others'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239988/filesystemwatcher-vs-polling-to-watch-for-file-changes)) experience. So if there is any chance of even moderate contention on the target folder I would use some kind of polling solution instead of file watcher.

That said, it won't tell you *who* did the change. Once you have deduced *what* has changed, you need to take additional steps for the "who" part. The filesystem stores quite sparse info, you won't find any source machine info. You could try mapping the fileshares that create these changes with different users, as you may deduce the modifying system from that:
[Finding the user who modified the shared drive folder files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19888612/finding-the-user-who-modified-the-shared-drive-folder-files).

If that is not an option, other solutions are much more complicated.

If you have access to the server hosting Z: you could turn on the [file audit log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh832139(v=vs.85).aspx) for that resource and deduce who the machine was from the event log (event ids 4663 / 5145). The source machine name will be logged in this case. Should be a breeze to enable it if it's a windows server (Directory properties/security/advanced/audit), but reading and synchronizing logs is more complicated.

If none of the solutions above is possible, you may be able to implement a user-space filesystem to proxy your file share, using something like [dokan](https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokan-dotnet). Source processes would map to your application instead of the fileshare, that way you could raise your own events or just write a detailed audit log to a database or whatever, and then you forward the actual commands to the fileshare. Very expensive and non-trivial solution though. But probably very fun.

Comment: I guess I have to find an Alternative way to do this... Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

FileSystemWatcher gives you notification on file changes.

If you want to use the file system for unique notification you'll need to create an isolated folder for each instance.

Something like :

Z:\Machine1\

Z:\Machine2\

Other option is to check who is the owner/created the file , but it can be really complicated in domain setups.