# File last modified by filesystemwatcher

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I need confirmation to proceed with development.
It looks like "file last modified by" is not available.

GETOWNER is available from system.IO.File. But OWNER is the original creator of the file.

That said, most apps save to temporary files before updating the actual file. The temporary file are always new and the owner of the temporary file is the user actually doing the work. My conclusion is not to watch for changed files and only watch for newly created files - correct?

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out username(who) modified file in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660235/find-out-usernamewho-modified-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Dominik is correct ... currently the final post at the link has a workable solution ... please delete this question / post.