# File Monitoring in VB.NET

Tags: file, monitoring

I want monitor a folder to view access to it. I find source in VB.NET languages programming and view the FileSystemWatcher class but in this class i can not find who change the folder.
can i find who create,delete or access a file in folder?
thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out username(who) modified file in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660235/find-out-usernamewho-modified-file-in-c-sharp)

The above in C# but you should be able to port it over.

Comment: i see the code but do not work!when a file delete code do not correct response.